# how to determine the width of a corridor using kinect on turtlebot

Tags: ros, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a project to do a formation change and I need to figure the width of a door where turtlebot must know if it can pass through or not.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239335/how-to-determine-the-width-of-a-corridor-using-kinect-on-turtlebot/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nominally, the turltebot can pass through a space that is larger than its physical size.

The standard implementation of navigation on the turtlebot builds an occupancy grid using the kinect data, inflates the obstacles by the robot's radius (plus some padding), and any remaining open grid cells are places where the turtlebot can safely navigate.

This is pretty much **the** standard implementation of navigation in ROS and is widely documented in both robotics literature and in the [costmap_2d package](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d), which is part of the larger ROS [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-12**:
Hi ahendrix, could you show a code where I could implement it on my turtlebots please?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-12**:
Start by running the [turtlebot_navigation demos](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation), and then explore the launch files and the configuration that they use.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-12**:
I would really like to put it in my code where once the turtlebot detects that the corridor is small it will go in straight line and once they are out they will go back to their original formation.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-12**:
or is there a particular launch file from the package above turtlebot_navigation demos and what it does?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-12**:
I'm confused, are you using one turtlebot or many? Your initial question used the singluar (one turtlebot), but it sounds like you want to control several turtlebots.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-12**:
In either case, you should start by running the demo that is close to what you want to do, and then start reading that launch file and the launch files it contains to understand how it is set up.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-13**:
Currently, I am working with 2 robots where the leader will 1) if the door is wide enough it will send no formation change 2) if the door is small but able to fit 1 robot it will send formation change.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-18**:
what is the launch file for the turtlebot obstacle avoidance?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-19**:
From the [Turtlebot autonomous navigation demo](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map), the launch file for doing localization, navigation and obstacle avoidance is `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch` .

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-23**:
I am looking over it for the past 4 days now. It will take me a sometime to make it work.